# Send data with button from another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, send

I would like to send a data to `update` action from `new` action with a button. 
So if user clicks to cancel button;

```
<%= button_to "Cancel", {:controller => :requests,
        :action => 'update', :user_id =>received.user.id, :id => received.id }, :value => "Cancelled" %>


The value has to be sent to the `update` action. But instead I receive an error;

 Started POST "/user/295/requests/29" for ::1 at 2015-10-17 12:35:30 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/boats/295/requests/29"):
```

and the request controller;

```
def update
     @request = Request.find(params[:id])
     puts situation = params[:situation]
     if @request.update_attributes(situation)
      flash[:success] = "Approved"
      redirect_to new_user_request(current_user.id)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_request(current_user.id)
    end
```

Basically, would like to send a text data to update action in requests controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arup's answer will get the [`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) working for you.

To give you some code, you'll need the following:

```
<%= button_to "Cancelled", requests_path(received.id, received.user.id), method: :put %>
```

---

In regards the code itself, you'd be better off doing this:

```
<%= button_to "Cancelled", requests_path(received.id, received.user.id), method: :put, {params: {situation: "Cancelled"}} %>

#app/controllers/situations_controller.rb
class SituationsController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @situation = Situation.find params[:id]
      @situation.update situation_params
   end

   private

   def situation_params
      params.require(:situation).permit(:situation)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to update the `@situation` to have a "situation" of "cancelled".

I would recommend several fixes:

1. You should rename your "situation" column to `status` (so you can call `@situation.status`
2. You should make your `status` column less dependent on text -- it should have a rigid spec, maybe make it `boolean` or something. This will allow you to call something like `@situation.active?`
3. You should always use the Rails [path helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) wherever you can. Sending a hash of controller/action information is fine, but it's best to use the inbuilt paths for better convention

Comment: Ok, Thank you the clarification.